# How do I calculate free disk space on Linux in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I want calculate and display the free space of the home filesystem but there are 3-4 users, and all should be in javascript, how can we do ?

I know in linux shell , we can do :

```
df -h
```

But in javascript it's not

Comment: You cannot access the file system from JavaScript.  You'll have to check it from PHP.

Comment: That's not the point of javascript ... It's mainly used for DOM manipulation not system commands ... why do you want to achieve this ? What if your client runs windows ?

Comment: Because for my friends , I have create a VPS, and in a manager, they want to see the free space in their home . It's only on my server ( debian )

Answer (score 6):

[Node diskusage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/diskusage) will do this. Please refer to the [diskusage docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/diskusage) for more information about the package:

```
import { check } from "diskusage";

const log = console.log.bind(console);

async function getFreeSpace(path) {
  const diskUsage = await check(path);
  log(`Disk space available to the current user: ${diskUsage.free}`);
  log(`Disk space physically free: ${diskUsage.free}`);
  log(`Total disk space (free + used): ${diskUsage.free}`);
}

getFreeSpace("/home/mike");
```

Comment: Ok, thanks, but where the free space are they display ? In my html page ?

Comment: @KévinBobo In a command line terminal. JS in web pages normally doesn't get access to your full disk, only part of it (about 50MB right now). This is for security reasons. You have to install native programs (eg, like node and this script) to access your full hard disk.

Comment: Yes, but the best is the resulat display on my webUI :/ because my friends aren't access to the terminal ( for security )

Comment: You could still show the output - eg, run the script from cron on your friends machines, and HTTP POST the results as JSON to a web server. But your friends *will* have to install the script themselves (or you could log in to their Linux machine via SSH and do it for them).

Comment: Hope you don't mind me adding a bit more details - feel free to roll back..

Comment: @iLuvLogix not at all! Thanks for keeping the answer fresh - you can move it from callbacks to promises too.

Comment: Added some more info since my code is [currently busy compiling](https://xkcd.com/303/).. ;)

Comment: @iLuvLogix nice! I've edited your changes down to a single, modern example - callbacks and .then() are just noise. Also since TS types are loaded automatically we don't need the extra bits.

Answer (score 6):

NodeJS, in v19.6, added support for `statfs` and `statfsSync`.

```
import { statfs } from 'fs';

// path in mounted volume
const pathToCheck = '/';

const space = statfs(pathToCheck, (err, stats) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  console.log('Total free space',stats.bsize*stats.bfree);
  console.log('Available for user',stats.bsize*stats.bavail);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! It's worked on node 18 also

Answer (score 1):

What JavaScript environment are you using? NodeJS has a childprocess module that you can use to spawn a df command, see http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html for more details.

I imagine that you're not attempting this in a browser based JavaScript sandbox.

Comment: I use jquery too . I need to install NodeJS ?

Comment: Yeah, or some sort of server side language to return the value and server it up as a value or object to your jQuery.

JavaScript runs in a browser sandbox and doesn't have access to the resources of either the client or server natively, you'd have to make it aware of the information by using some other means.

As another poster suggested Node DiskFree might be suitable. The advantage to node is that if you're already using JavaScript it does mean you don't mentally context switch from multiple languages, that and its modules.

Comment: And, can you show me the childprocess for the df command ? How that work ?

Comment: Using the docs here: [Node](http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options)

I'd do it the way their example is.

    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
    var df = spawn('df', ['-h']);

    df.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stdout: ' + data);
    });

    df.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
      console.log('stderr: ' + data);
    });

    df.on('close', function (code) {
      console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
    });

Have you used NodeJS before though, do you know how to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

shameless plug - 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/microstats

Can also be configured to alert the user when disk space crosses user defined threshold. works for linux, macOS and windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use diskusage npm and child_process.exec('df / -h') to get this parameter.
but diskusage npm is more reliable and easy to use. if you use cp.exec('...') you should process the returned string by yourself to retrieve the desired parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by running the command `df -h > df.txt` which writes the `df -h` output to a file named `df.txt`. Then you could read the file and match a regex to it.

```js
const { execSync } = require('child_process');
const { readFileSync, unlinkSync } = require('fs')

var space;

execSync('df -h > df.txt');

space = readFileSync('df.txt', (data, err) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
}).toString().match(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+?../)[0]

console.log(space)
```

Comment: This works well, but you'll need to use `execSync` instead of `exec`

Comment: This is an awful way to waste CPU cycles on a simple operation.